# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'resources'

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring, i am currently using spring 4

once the war is deployed into JCS-SaaS (cloud) i am getting below error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 33 in XML document from class path resource
>   [pepsiServlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 62;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'resources'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"],
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
>
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33;
>   columnNumber: 62; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
>   starting with element 'resources'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"],
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itc</groupId>
    <artifactId>pepsiIndIntegration</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pepsiIndIntegration Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <apache.commons.version>3.4</apache.commons.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JUnit Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Org Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle Driver Dependency -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>oracle</groupId> <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${oracle.driver.path}</systemPath> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for common file upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId> <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId> 
            <version>2.9.1</version> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>pepsiIndIntegration</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extensions>
                        <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:3.1.2</extension>
                    </extensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf/wsdl2java</sourceRoot>
                            <!-- <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf/wsdl2java</sourceRoot> -->
                            <!-- <defaultOptions> <bindingFiles> <bindingFile>${binding}/binding.xml</bindingFile> 
                                </bindingFiles> </defaultOptions> -->
                            <wsdlRoot>${wsdls}</wsdlRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>https://someurl:someport/xyz/abc?wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <!-- Loading Beans -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:pepsiBeans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Dispatched Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pepsiServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:pepsiServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pepsiServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is my pepsiServlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.pepsi" />
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- Initialization for data source -->
<!--    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin@hostname:port:service/sid" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="USER_NAME" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="PASSWORD" />
    </beans:bean> -->

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:ApplicationMessages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>


    <task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler"
        executor="executor" />
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" />


    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="pepsiIntgService" method="readFile"
            cron="${cronstring}" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <!-- <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" /> <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" 
        /> <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" /> </bean> <bean id="taskExecutorExample" 
        class="TaskExecutorExample"> <constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" /> </bean> -->
</beans:bean>
```

Below is the log after deploying into JCS-SaaS

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 33 in XML document from class path resource
>   [pepsiServlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 62;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'resources'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"],
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>     at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:2037)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:2011)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1930)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3226)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1529)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:488)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:84)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:573)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:327)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:849)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1273)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:441)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:268)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:226) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 62;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'resources'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"],
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:452)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3230)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1790)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:760)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:504)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338)
>     at
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>     ... 57 more

If an file needs to be changed please help me out, thanks

Comment: Have you tried <mvc:resources in line 33 of pepsiServlet-context.xml?

Comment: @mm759, i have changed and worked now i am facing new error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your `XML` file:

#### 1. Incorrect closing tag

Your **closing tag is not correct**, it should rather be:

```
</beans:beans> (not </beans:bean>)
```

Because of that your XML document corresponding to `pepsiServlet-context.xml` is not [**well-formed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) so it cannot be parsed.

#### 2. Missing prefix to `resources`

Your second issue is related to the fact that you forgot to add the **prefix** `mvc` to `resources` which makes your XML file **invalid**, it should be:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Comment: thanks it worked but now i ended up with new error(Question edited) :- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Comment: @user2587669 this is a totally different problem, you should ask a new question because now our answers are totally outdated and unrelated to your new problem. Please revert your edit and ask another question instead to allow other people having the same problem to find our answers.

Answer (score 2):

This tag in your file pepsiServlet-context.xml

```
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

Not is correct version or that old, i'm use:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

than use correct tag with orientation the URL xsd, that case only use **bean**

Comment: ok, than make a correct solution and then use one time for solve problem propose. after other help other users